# Can't get value of nodes in XML file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I'm trying get data for all my rows in xml file, but i get data only for one column when use element_name 'Data' in other case i have empty list. Please help.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = {'doc': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet', 'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

tree = ET.parse('2307.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


def getvalueofnode(node, element_name):
    """Return text of the element with the given name or None."""
    element = node.find(f'.//doc:{element_name}', ns)
    return element.text if element is not None else ''


def main():
    data = []
    for i, node in enumerate(root.findall('.//doc:Row', ns)):
        if i > 0:  # skip header row
            data.append({
                'Накладная №': getvalueofnode(node, 'Data'),
                'Время изготовления замеса': getvalueofnode(node, 'Время изготовления замеса'),
                'Опознавание рецепта': getvalueofnode(node, 'Опознавание рецепта')
            })
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


df = main()
print(df)
```

My Output:

Накладная № Время изготовления замеса Опознавание рецепта

0      1023972
1      1023972
2      1023972
3      1023972
4      1023973
5      1023973
6      1023974
7      1023975
8      1023975
9      1023975
10     1023975
11     1023975
12     1023975
13     1023975
14     1023976

Part of XML data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"><DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Keywords>Version 1.0</Keywords></DocumentProperties><Styles><Style ss:ID="s22"><NumberFormat ss:Format="General Date"/></Style><Style ss:ID="s63"><Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:Rotate="90"/></Style></Styles><Worksheet ss:Name="Порционный режим"><Table><Row ss:Index="1"><Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Накладная №</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Время изготовления замеса</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Опознавание рецепта</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Имя рецепта</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Категория рецепта</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="6" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Номер замеса</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="7" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Бункер отгрузки</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="8" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Время смешивания</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="9" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Кол-во продукции</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="10" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Рецепт изменён</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="11" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Взятие пробы</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="12" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пенный битум</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="13" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Температура смеси Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="14" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Температура смеси Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="15" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Температура смеси Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="16" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Температура смеси Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="17" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="18" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="19" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="20" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="21" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="22" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="23" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="24" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="25" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="26" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="27" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="28" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="29" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bit 1 (AB01)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="30" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="31" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="32" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="33" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="34" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="35" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="36" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="37" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="38" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="39" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="40" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="41" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="42" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Пыль (AEF01)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="43" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="44" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="45" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="46" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="47" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="48" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="49" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="50" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="51" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="52" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="53" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="54" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="55" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Минеральный порошок (AFF01)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="56" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="57" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="58" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="59" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="60" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="61" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="62" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="63" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="64" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="65" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="66" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="67" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="68" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">Bypass (AM01)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="69" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="70" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="71" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="72" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="73" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="74" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="75" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="76" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="77" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="78" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="79" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="80" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="81" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">0-5 (AM02)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="82" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="83" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="84" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="85" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="86" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="87" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="88" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="89" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="90" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="91" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="92" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="93" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="94" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">5-10 (AM03)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="95" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="96" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="97" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="98" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="99" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="100" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="101" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="102" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="103" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="104" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="105" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="106" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="107" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">10-15 (AM04)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="108" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="109" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="110" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="111" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="112" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="113" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="114" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="115" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="116" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="117" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="118" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="119" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="120" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">15-20 (AM05)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="121" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Кол-во компонента Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="122" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Кол-во компонента Надо единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="123" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Компоненты без засчёта Надо</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="124" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Кол-во компонента Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="125" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Кол-во компонента Есть единица</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="126" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Компоненты без засчёта Есть</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="127" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Ручное вмешательство при работе</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="128" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Допуск при дозации акцептирован</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="129" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Автоматическая коррекция заданного значения</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="130" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Дозацию продолжить</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="131" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Синхронизация с последующей фазой</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="132" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Температура компонента</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="133" ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="String">20-40 (AM06)@Температура компонента единица</Data></Cell></Row><Row ss:Index="2"><Cell ss:Index="1"><Data ss:Type="String">1023972</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2022-07-23T09:06:06.813</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="3"><Data ss:Type="String">В-10.</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="4"><Data ss:Type="String">В-10.</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="6"><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="7"><Data ss:Type="String">1. Silo</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="8"><Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="Number">3.02739</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="10"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="11"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="12"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="13"><Data ss:Type="Number">50</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="14"><Data ss:Type="String">°C</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="15"><Data ss:Type="Number">161.105</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="16"><Data ss:Type="String">°C</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="17"><Data ss:Type="Number">189.1</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="18"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="19"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="20"><Data ss:Type="Number">187.599</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="21"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="22"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="23"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="24"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="25"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="26"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="27"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="28"><Data ss:Type="Number">160.852</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="29"><Data ss:Type="String">°C</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="30"><Data ss:Type="Number">91.5</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="31"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="32"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="33"><Data ss:Type="Number">86.3552</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="34"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="35"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="36"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="37"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="38"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="39"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="40"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="43"><Data ss:Type="Number">91.5</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="44"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="45"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="46"><Data ss:Type="Number">89.5425</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="47"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="48"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="49"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="50"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="51"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="52"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="53"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="69"><Data ss:Type="Number">1811.7</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="70"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="71"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="72"><Data ss:Type="Number">1791.45</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="73"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="74"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="75"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="76"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="77"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="78"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="79"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="80"><Data ss:Type="Number">65.955</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="81"><Data ss:Type="String">°C</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="82"><Data ss:Type="Number">866.2</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="83"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="84"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="85"><Data ss:Type="Number">872.447</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="86"><Data ss:Type="String">kg</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="87"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="88"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="89"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="90"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="91"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="92"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell></Row></Table></Worksheet></Workbook>
```

Comment: You are mixing element names with element values in getvalueofnode args. If you want to search by value the xpath should be something like `f'.//doc:Data[.="Опознавание рецепта"]'`

Comment: I guess that's good point. Will think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help. I found a solution to the task that works for me. In my solution task, I first find the column indexes def find_cell_indexes(xml_file_path, row_index, column_names): that I am interested in in the list (sometimes they may or may not be in the XML file). And finally, def getvalueofnode(node):. Sorry for the russian language in the code, unfortunately it is in the XML file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


def find_cell_indexes(xml_file_path, row_index, column_names):
    # Parse the XML file and get the root element
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Define the namespaces used in the XML file
    ns = {'doc': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet',
          'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}

    # Find the row element with the specified index
    row_element = root.find(f'.//doc:Row[@ss:Index="{row_index}"]', ns)

    if row_element is not None:
        # Find the cell elements in the row that correspond to the specified column names
        indexes = []
        for column_name in column_names:
            found_column = False
            for cell_element in row_element.findall('.//doc:Cell', ns):
                cell_data_element = cell_element.find('.//doc:Data', ns)
                if cell_data_element.text == column_name:
                    cell_items = cell_element.items()
                    indexes.append(cell_items[0][1])
                    found_column = True
                    break
            if not found_column:
                indexes.append('')
        return indexes

    # If the row is not found, return an empty list
    return []


xml_file_path = '2307.xml'
row_index = 1  # Assuming the header row is the first row
column_names = ['Накладная №', 'Время изготовления замеса', 'Имя рецепта', 'Кол- во продукции',
                'Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Есть', 'Bitumen pipe']
cell_indexes = find_cell_indexes(xml_file_path, row_index, column_names)

print(cell_indexes)  # Output: [1, 2]

ns = {"doc": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet", "ss": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}
tree = ET.parse("2307.xml")
root = tree.getroot()


def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else ''


def main():
    data = []
    for i, node in enumerate(root.findall('.//doc:Row', ns)):
        if i > 0:
            data.append({'doc_num': getvalueofnode(node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[0]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'time_prod': getvalueofnode(
                             node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[1]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'idr': getvalueofnode(node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[2]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'qtty': getvalueofnode(node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[3]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'bitum': getvalueofnode(node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[4]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         'Bitumen pipe': getvalueofnode(
                             node.find(f'doc:Cell[@ss:Index="{cell_indexes[5]}"]/doc:Data', ns)),
                         })
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


df = main()

print(df)
```

Result:

['1', '2', '4', '9', '20', '']

```
doc_num                time_prod    idr     qtty    bitum Bitumen pipe
```

0   1023972  2022-07-23T09:06:06.813  В-10.  3.02739  187.599
1   1023972  2022-07-23T09:06:59.747  В-10.  3.08288  189.614
2   1023972  2022-07-23T09:07:41.120  В-10.  1.93264  119.995
3   1023972  2022-07-23T09:08:20.410  В-10.  1.97369  120.898
4   1023973  2022-07-23T09:09:24.397  В-10.   1.7387  109.418
5   1023973  2022-07-23T09:10:03.280  В-10.   1.7441  110.787
6   1023974  2022-07-23T09:11:40.593  КЗ-10  2.03064  97.3793
7   1023975  2022-07-23T09:12:32.547  В-10.  3.08609  190.498
8   1023975  2022-07-23T09:13:22.643  В-10.  3.06997  190.194
9   1023975  2022-07-23T09:14:21.627  В-10.  3.05432  190.947
10  1023975  2022-07-23T09:15:34.983  В-10.  3.03267  190.264
11  1023975  2022-07-23T09:16:46.077  В-10.  3.03047  191.279
12  1023975  2022-07-23T09:17:30.267  В-10.   2.3624  147.301
13  1023975  2022-07-23T09:18:23.987  В-10.  2.36726  147.873
14  1023976  2022-07-23T09:21:04.580  В-10.  3.05764  190.259
15  1023976  2022-07-23T09:21:49.820  В-10.  3.05276  190.801
16  1023976  2022-07-23T09:22:36.020  В-10.  3.04138  190.861
17  1023976  2022-07-23T09:23:21.063  В-10.  3.04716  190.194
18  1023976  2022-07-23T09:24:09.067  В-10.  3.07738  190.696
19  1023976  2022-07-23T09:25:08.350  В-10.  3.06708  190.381
20  1023976  2022-07-23T09:26:20.810  В-10.  3.05788   190.06
21  1023976  2022-07-23T09:27:25.423  В-10.  3.04395  189.959
22  1023976  2022-07-23T09:28:27.750  В-10.  2.78911   174.02
23  1023976  2022-07-23T09:29:54.223  В-10.  2.78346  173.047
24  1023977  2022-07-23T10:02:13.430  В-10.  3.04915  190.329
25  1023977  2022-07-23T10:02:53.953  В-10.  1.98642  122.926
26  1023977  2022-07-23T10:03:30.620  В-10.  1.96784  122.874
27  1023978  2022-07-23T10:48:47.767  В-10.  3.03407  189.892
28  1023978  2022-07-23T10:49:38.930  В-10.  3.06354  190.861
29  1023978  2022-07-23T10:51:23.293  В-10.  1.94399  122.194
30  1023978  2022-07-23T10:52:00.743  В-10.  1.96193  122.483
31  1023979  2022-07-23T10:54:21.910  В-10.  2.49058  155.521
32  1023979  2022-07-23T10:55:00.860  В-10.  2.50879  155.907
33  1023980  2022-07-23T11:21:05.890  В-10.  2.50959  156.563
34  1023980  2022-07-23T11:24:50.700  В-10.   2.5009  154.343
35  1023981  2022-07-23T11:37:20.167  В-10.   2.5077  156.348
36  1023981  2022-07-23T11:39:35.803  В-10.  2.50112  154.129

Answer (score 0):

If you use read_xml() from pandas with the path like:

```
import pandas as ET
df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath=(".//ns0:Cell"), namespaces={"ns0":"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"})
print(df)
```

Gives you this output:

```
    Index StyleID                                 Data
0       1     s63                          Накладная №
1       2     s63            Время изготовления замеса
2       3     s63                  Опознавание рецепта
3       4     s63                          Имя рецепта
4       5     s63                    Категория рецепта
5       6     s63                         Номер замеса
6       7     s63                      Бункер отгрузки
7       8     s63                     Время смешивания
8       9     s63                     Кол-во продукции
9      10     s63                       Рецепт изменён
10     11     s63                         Взятие пробы
11     12     s63                         Пенный битум
12     13     s63               Температура смеси Надо
13     14     s63       Температура смеси Надо единица
14     15     s63               Температура смеси Есть
15     16     s63       Температура смеси Есть единица
16     17     s63  Bit 1 (AB01)@Кол-во компонента Надо
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but data in DATA column on your code is the columns name's in my case. My code read rows step by step end must put data according to column name like you see in my output example.

Comment: Your output example figures are not into the xml available, this is what I am wondering? Where comes this from. Is this the row number from enumerate or what?

Comment: I'm sorry, My bad, I'm updated an xml data in post. There is only part of the data, because the file is very large.

Comment: The columns in your now shared xml is 133, but the columns of the values are only 74. df ERROR -> Shape of passed values is (74, 1), indices imply (74, 133)

Comment: Like i said, can't put all document here, because it's to large.

Comment: Sure, but the dummy should work, if you assume an answer. I will not waste more time.